# How do virtual particles cause an attraction?

Tags: forces, particle-physics, interactions, virtual-particles, strong-force

How do virtual particles such as photons cause a force between particles such as an attraction between protons and electrons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photons acting as carriers of both attractive and repulsive forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169378/)

Comment: maybe this answer of mine to a similar question will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189605/how-does-a-photon-mediate-both-electric-attraction-and-repulsion