# How photons move and create electric force?

Tags: electric-fields

[image]

I have a figure of the electric field lines of two point charges as above. I have a question, do photons follow electric lines of force, then "collision" with negative charges and create an electric force?

Comment: No. That's not what happens here. You're perhaps mistaking this with the QED description where there is the exchange of _virtual_ photons. You may find [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61095/photon-as-the-carrier-of-the-electromagnetic-force) question useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photon as the carrier of the electromagnetic force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61095/)